# How do I properly cast this?

Tags: c#, casting

How do I properly set the accessBehavior variable?

```
public sealed class FileAccess : ProjectAccess, IAccess<File>

    interface IAccess<T> where T : ITfsType



        public abstract class Access<T>
        {
            private IAccess<T> accessBehavior;
            public Access()
            {
                FileAccess fa = new FileAccess();
                accessBehavior = //what to assign?
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is confusing, you have a parameter named ITfsType of type `string` and a type called ITfsType?

Comment: going to be using a factory, so the string will be passed to it.

Comment: I removed it...  It is irrelevant for my question

Comment: right...  thanks...  That was an unconstructive comment.  I have an instance shown above, setting the IAccess instance to fa is not straight forward (due to constraints) it is not allowing a direct cast.

Comment: This is confusing at most, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @bojanskr I think he wants to assign fa to it but wants to cast it in some way. But he needs to bind the T in Access to a type where file is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileAccess fa = new FileAccess();
IAccess<T> test = fa as IAccess<T>;
```

This was my answer.  I can now interact with test with the IAccess interface but the concrete type assigned is FileAccess.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way to cast it based on what you have. `FileAcccess` implements `IAccess<File>`, but `accessBehavior`'s type argument is not known. There is no relation between `T`, which can be any type, and `File`.

If you had something like:

```
private IAccess<File> accessBehavior;
```

Then you could just assign it. Otherwise, you'd need a non-generic base interface, like:

```
public interface IAccess {
}

public interface IAccess<T> : IAccess {
}


public abstract class Access<T>
{
    private IAccess accessBehavior;

    public Access()
     {
         FileAccess fa = new FileAccess();
         accessBehavior = fa;
     }
 }
```

But you'd lose the strong typing of the generic type parameter on the members of `IAccess`.